# How to change data file format from Gnuplot to Tikz errorbars

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to change the format of Gnuplot errorbar data to LaTeX/Tikz format.

For example, the Gnuplot format data is:

```
5 74.92725 74.7028332590511 75.1516667409489
112.5 112.55897 112.259769398083 112.858170601917
150 149.69954 149.34363510537 150.05544489463
187.5 187.17666 186.776888667849 187.576431332151
225 224.99652 224.445862626087 225.547177373913
262.5 262.41776 261.885021624469 262.950498375531
300 292.136265549781 292.001497790752 292.271033308809
337.5 291.919651585991 291.609116120618 292.230187051365
375 291.422462501904 291.176186050372 291.668738953436
412.5 291.280355443992 290.980439760169 291.580271127815
450 291.280355443992 290.980439760169 291.580271127815
```

and the Tikz format I need is this:

```
(75     ,74.92725 )         -=(0,74.7028332590511- 74.92725 )        +=(0, 75.1516667409489 - 74.92725 )    
(112.5  ,112.55897)         -=(0,112.259769398083- 112.55897)        +=(0, 112.858170601917 - 112.55897)    
(150    ,149.69954)         -=(0,149.34363510537 - 149.69954)        +=(0, 150.05544489463  - 149.69954)    
(187.5  ,187.17666)         -=(0,186.776888667849- 187.17666)        +=(0, 187.576431332151 - 187.17666)    
(225    ,224.99652)         -=(0,224.445862626087- 224.99652)        +=(0, 225.547177373913 - 224.99652)    
(262.5  ,262.41776)         -=(0,261.885021624469- 262.41776)        +=(0, 262.950498375531 - 262.41776)    
(300    ,292.136265549781)  -=(0,292.001497790752- 292.136265549781) +=(0, 292.271033308809 - 292.136265549781)
(337.5  ,291.919651585991)  -=(0,291.609116120618- 291.919651585991) +=(0, 292.230187051365 - 291.919651585991)
(375    ,291.422462501904)  -=(0,291.176186050372- 291.422462501904) +=(0, 291.668738953436 - 291.422462501904)
(412.5  ,291.280355443992)  -=(0,290.980439760169- 291.280355443992) +=(0, 291.580271127815 - 291.280355443992)
```

I have tabulated these result to make it clearer but it is not necessary for Tikz.

I have many files of this type and I would like to know if there is any command to make it easier.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk '{printf("(%s, %s) -=(0, %s-%s) +=(0, %s-%s)\n",$1,$2,$3,$2,$4,$2)}'
```

or even:

```
for a in *.gnudata
do
   awk '....' "$a" > "$a".tikzdata
done
```